# Using Factor analysis dynamically by various markets/regions

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, factor-analysis

I need to run factor analysis based on markets so I created a list using the split function:

```
    splitx <- split(data,list(data$econ_gas,data$econ_unemp,data$open),data$MKT)
```

And then I have looped through the 'splitx' list to run  the factor analysis as follows:

```
    for (i in 1:length(splitx)) 
     {

      factanal(~ ., data = splitx, factors = 1) 

     }
```

I get the following error:

Error in factanal(splitx, factors = 1) : factor analysis applies only to numerical variables.

I am also giving a snapshot of the data I am working on:

```
    MKT econ_unemp  econ_gas open
    504 0.0743088   3.461    38
    504 0.0740673   3.448    38
    504 0.0740673   3.455    38
    504 0.0740673   3.42     38
    504 0.072682    3.391    38
    505 0.0692244   3.345    38
    505 0.0692244   3.381    38
    505 0.0692244   3.484    38
    505 0.0692244   3.488    38
```

Can I get some help on this.

Comment: do you have any non-numeric variables? What is `str(data)`?

Comment: You might also want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: No , I don't have non numeric data .All I have are the different markets & the macro variables

Comment: A reproducible example (even of one list element) would be ideal. If you are unable to provide one, please show enough summaries (`str()`, `summary()`, histograms...) for us to understand your data.

Comment: Please edit your question, comment section is not meant to hold data.

Comment: I have edited my question thanks for pointing out.